# preg match for get all kind of phone numbers from a page using php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am writing a little script for scrap phone numbers from web page. this page has various format of phone numbers like below

```
-PH:(07) 46 3000 66, BUSINESS HOURS, 9-5 MON-FRI, 9-12 SAT-SUN.
-Please phone 54974211 or 0411053074 both between 10 am – 8 pm or 
-or Phone 07 5497 1000 if you get 
-Email or ph 0755431528. 
-Phone 0414 791 796 
-Or ph 0418117617
```

I used some regx patterns like

```
preg_match_all('/([\w+\.]*\w+@[\w+\.]*\w+[\w+\-\w+]*\.\w+)/is',$pagecontents,$results);
var_dump($results);
```

But i ant figure out how can i get all this kind of phone numbers. anyone can help me to get all kind of phone numbers from the page using preg_match or anyother PHP way. 
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my experience with cleaning data from websites, it is imposible to take all telephone numbers (from free text) unless you will write all possible compinations.

Using yours text example try this

```
preg_match_all('/(ph:|ph |phone)([\(\)\d or\-]+?)([^\(\)\d or\-]|$)/is',$pagecontents,$results);
var_dump($results[2]);
```

Comment: this works but getting results with PH:(07)46 3000 66, like this can we get rid of PH: , like ones. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with [this one](http://regexr.com?36n89): `\(?\d+\)?(\s*\d+){3}`.

Comment: getting error
 preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: yeah, actually I posted only regular expression, to use it within `preg_match_all php function` you have to encapsulate it with `/` and escape some chars.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this pattern, demo:

```
$pattern = '~(?>(\()?0\d(?(1)\))\s?+)?+\d\d\s?+(?>\d{3}\s?\d{3}|(?:\d\d\s??){3})~';
$subject = <<<'LOD'
-PH:(07) 46 3000 66, BUSINESS HOURS, 9-5 MON-FRI, 9-12 SAT-SUN.
-Please phone 54974211 or 0411053074 both between 10 am – 8 pm or 
-or Phone 07 5497 1000 if you get 
-Email or ph 0755431528. 
-Phone 0414 791 796 
-Or ph 0418117617
LOD;

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: the thing is this also getting google analytic codes and adsence account ids as phone numbers. i think need some enhancements  :)

Comment: @smithbandara: try to add word boundaries or lookarounds to check if there are no digits around.